# Google Autocomplete - Disable arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project that requires results coming back from the places api to be filtered out. I'm doing this through the hide() function.

```
$(object).hide();
```

However, if the user uses the arrow keys to scroll through the results, the results are shown in the input.

What I'm trying to do is to disable arrow key navigation for that input box.

I've tried using keydown event checks for that but the arrow key navigation continues to work.

```
$('#search').bind('keydown', function(e) {
            var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if(key == 40 || key == 38) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
```

Is there something that I am missing? I've also tried using the bindFirst plugin -
https://github.com/private-face/jquery.bind-first

Comment: So Instead of arrow keys how the user should select suggestions?

Comment: The mouse or their enter keys. There is an entirely separate page for those who do not have access to a mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those having the same problem, here's what I found out.

The bind event fires before the google event binding. So what eventually solved my problem was -

```
$('#search').bind('keydown', function (event) {
 setTimeout(function() {
   // do things here
   $('.pac-item').removeClass('.pac-item-selected');
   event.stopPropagation();
   return false;
 }, 2);
});
```

It solves my problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try.

Keep a reference to the disabling function & Unbind it when you are ready to enable.

For eg.

```
var arrKey = new Array(37, 38, 39, 40);
var disableArrowKeys = function(e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, arrKey)>=0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}


$(document).keydown(disableArrowKeys);

// When you are ready to enable, Unbind the function.

$(document).unbind('keydown', disableArrowKeys);
```

Comment: I've already used this code from another SO answer and it does not work with my need.

Comment: How do you want to customize then?

Comment: Please check my last post. I'm sure the code snippet you posted would work combined with that.